# Retrieve users private token with Gitlab python API

Tags: gitlab-api

I am trying to retrieve all users' private token and SSH keys with gitlab API (v4) using an admin private token in my curl requests.

I can get a user SSH key by running the following command :

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: my_admin_token" "https://gitlab.my_gitlab.com/api/v4/users/user_id/keys"
```

But I can't find a similar way to get his private token (I need it for further applications in a python script). How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is impossible. When you create token you need to save it since you cannot access it later (see attached screenshot):

[image]

Comment: I understand now that it is not possible for the Personal Access Token (thank you for this info), but I am also looking for the "Private token", which can be found in Settings -> Account at any time. So I suppose it should be retrievable with gitlab API?

Answer (score 0):

Those tokens are not available through Gitlab API, on the other hand, if you want to make API calls as someone else, you can do so with https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#sudo.